# RecyclerView.OnClickListener vs View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I can implement both of them in my recyclerView holder

```
public class PagosPendientesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RecyclerView.OnClickListener
public class PagosPendientesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. They are the same interface. `RecyclerView` extends `ViewGroup` which extends `View`. You are implementing the same interface. I would use the second.

Comment: There is no additional code for RecyclerView listener?

Comment: it doesn't exists. What you are implementing is, in any case, View.OnClickListener.

Comment: OK, I think I get it, It is just hierarchy

Comment: exactly. It is  just hierarchy